# Integration of $2\cos x \ e^{2\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm currently working my way through last semesters exams and I'm trying to understand an particular equation:

$$\int 2\cos x \ e^{2 \sin x} dx$$

Now, apparently the solution to this one is just $\int_{}{} e^t dt$ with $t = 2\sin x$ and $dt = 2\cos x $. I've spend a fair amount of time on trying to understand why $2 \cos x $ in the original Integral just disappears in the end but wasn't able to find a satisfying answer and I'm  just wondering if anybody else could provide me with some clue.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} 2 \sin x = 2 \cos x dx$, so you have $\int du \cdot e^u$.

Comment: It's not that the $2\cos x$ disappears, it just reappears in a differrent form. Since $du=2\cos(x)\,dx$ the $2\cos(x)\,dx$ "disappears" if you will, and is replaced by $du$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $$\int f(g(x))f'(x)dx=\int f(t)dt , \hspace{5mm}\text{where} \hspace {5mm} t=g(x)$$

We get $$\int2\cos x e^{2\sin x}dx=\int e^tdt, t=2\sin x=e^{2\sin x}+C $$

Answer (score 1):

This is because substituting $t=2\sin x$ means that $\dfrac{d}{dx}t=2\cos x$. Multiplying by $dx$ on both sides, $dt=2\cos x\; dx$. Can you continue?